# Make background color 100% width of automatically generated flexbox row

Tags: html, css

I want the first row of my container (the one with logo and button) to be 100% gray, as it is.

However, I'm having trouble with the second row. I want the second row to be yellow. But I can't seem to make it happen.
The color of the container keeps invading the second row. How do I make the second row to be 100% wide and yellow?  I've tried `width: 100%`, but it didn't solve the problem.

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(210, 210, 210);
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#container {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: baseline;
  background-color: rgb(97, 97, 97);
}

#Hyperlinks {
  text-align: right;
  background-color: darkgoldenrod;
}

#Logo {
  width: 20%;
}

#Button {
  width: 80%;
  text-align: right;
}

#Button button {
  margin-right: 40px;
  background-color: rgba(27, 129, 107, 0.5);
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#Logo p {
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande';
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 40px;
}

#Hyperlinks a {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

#Hyperlinks ul {
  text-align: left;
  padding-inline-start: 0;
  margin-block-start: 0;
  margin-block-end: 0;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

#Hyperlinks>ul>li {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 50px 10px 2px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#Hyperlinks ul ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="Logo">
      <p>MySitee.com</p>
    </div>
    <div id="Button">
      <button type="button">Click me</button>
    </div>
    <div id="Hyperlinks">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tutorial</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Tutorial 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tutorial 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tutorial 3</a></li>
          </ul>
          <!-- repare onde o li é quebrado... esse ul fica dentro dele, filho msm -->
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Newsletter</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">News 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">News 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">News 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: 100% width will work - are you sure you are applying it to the right element?

Comment: I've tried to apply to #Hyperlinks, it expands the yellow area, but it still have some small grey borders.

Comment: Think about it for a second... What does the container's `padding` do? ;)

Comment: I tried to balance out and put margin-left: -10px; margin-right: -10px; margin-bottom: -10px; it worked partially, all margins except the right one were gone, I dont know why =(

Comment: Instead of trying to "undo" the padding on 3 sides, I'd suggest removing it altogether from the container and add it to the elements in the first row instead - much cleaner and easier to maintain. UPDATE - actually, you already hve padding on your 1st row elements, so there is no need for the padding at all!

Comment: It does make sense, I will try to adjust the code, thank you !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove the `gray color` which is invaded by `#container`, it is needed to fill the empty space with the `#hyperlink` and this can be done using `flex-grow: 1`.

And still, you can see the gray borders. This was made by the `padding` option of `#container` class. And to remove it on child `#hyperlink` class, it is needed to set the `margin` css attribute with the reverse value of parent `padding` css. So for example, if `#container` contains `padding-left: 10px;`, to remove it, it is needed to set `margin-left: -10px` css on `#hyperlink`.

```css
body{
    background-color: rgb(210,210,210);
    margin:0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#container{
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row; 
    flex-wrap: wrap; 
    align-items: baseline; 
    background-color: rgb(97, 97, 97);
}

#Hyperlinks{
    text-align: right;
    background-color: darkgoldenrod;
    
    flex-grow: 1;
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-right: -10px;
    margin-bottom: -10px;
}

#Logo{
    width: 20%; 
}

#Button{
    width: 80%;
    text-align: right;
}

#Button button{
    margin-right: 40px;
    background-color: rgba(27, 129, 107,0.5);
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
}


#Logo p{
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande';
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    color: white;
    padding-left: 40px;
}

#Hyperlinks a{
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

#Hyperlinks ul{
    text-align: left;
    padding-inline-start: 0;
    margin-block-start: 0;
    margin-block-end: 0;
    margin-left: 40px;
}

#Hyperlinks>ul>li{
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 50px 10px 2px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

#Hyperlinks ul ul{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <nav>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="Logo">
                <p>MySitee.com</p>
            </div>
            <div id="Button">
                    <button type= "button">Click me</button>
            </div>
            <div id="Hyperlinks">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Tutorial</a>
                       <ul>
                           <li><a href="#">Tutorial 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Tutorial 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Tutorial 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- repare onde o li é quebrado... esse ul fica dentro dele, filho msm -->
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Newsletter</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">News 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">News 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">News 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Hey, it still has a grey border =( do you know how to remove it?

Comment: I have updated my answer. This is because of `padding` on `#container` class. So to remove the gray border, you need to set the `margin` property on `#hyperlink` class. @digolira2

Comment: wow, thank you!!!! =)
I just have one last question, why the negative margins worked well with flex-grow: 1, but with the width: 100% it doesn't work properly?

Comment: Currently, you are on `flex` layout, so `width: 100%` does mean nothing. You will know about `flex-grow` through this link. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex-grow.asp
And about the negative margins, the negative value is set because of parent padding. To remove the parent padding effect, it is needed to move the child `#hyperlink` to the left (-10px) so margin is needed for that. @digolira2

Comment: @digolira2 I'd still suggest removing the padding and adding it to the children, but Derek's answer still helped you so don't forget that you now have enough reputation to upvote helpful answers too :)